# How to find the closest table name for a given mis-spelled table name?

Tags: natural-language, similarities

Suppose a database has a list of tables. A user can enter a table name to get the table information. If he/she enters a mis-spelled table name, then the system needs to scan all table names and return the closest table name. For example,

Correct table name: prob_crm_score_us
Mis-spelled name: prob_c_score_us

Which NLP(or text similarity) method should I use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might want to have a look at the [Levenshtein (edit) distance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dv_bdR7LpS0).

The algorithm compares two strings and identifies how they differ by considering insertions (insert a new character), swaps (swap two characters) and deletions (delete a character), where each of these operations have a cost associated with it.

You can then compare the correct table against all misspelled names and take the one with the smallest distance.

You can achieve the table name comparison
using R as follows:

```
adist("prob_crm_score_us","prob_c_score_us")
>    [,1]
[1,]    2
```

The cost is 2 because there were two deletions(**bold**): prob_c**rm**_score_us